# Hive : Overwrite queries on s3 external tables is failing

Tags: amazon-s3, hive

Overwrite queries are failing on the external tables whose data is located on s3.I am using Hive 1.2

Steps to reproduce:

1)create a file with below 3 rows and place it at some location in s3

```
a,b,c
x,y,z
c,d,e
```

2)create external table:

```
create external table test(col1 string,col2 string,col3 string)
 row format delimited fields terminated by ',' location '<S3LocationOfAboveFile>'
```

3)Do insert overwrite on this table:

```
insert overwrite table test select * from test order by col1;
```

I get an error  and I see that the s3 file is deleted.

```
    Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException
(No such file or directory:<S3 location> )
```

Comment: You cannot overwrite the test table with the same table test. It has to be other table..

Comment: But this works in hdfs external table.

Comment: Can i know the hive version you are using ?

Comment: Version is Hive 1.2

Comment: Looks like it is fixed in the hive 2.x : https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/97008/hive-insert-into-s3-external-table-overwrites-whol.html